# I broke my network on my raspberry pi

Tags: ubuntu

As I was experimenting with various things I deleted the file /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml. Now I can't get any network (ethernet or wifi) to connect. So I can't ssh to fix things. I am on Ubuntu Server 20.02. I can't even find a terminal (shell) app in the default gui. Help?

Comment: the best advice would be to restore your most recent backup ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easily done and its good to play..

Login to your machine via the console.. and use your editor of choice to edit /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml.

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: true
            match:
                driver: bcmgenet smsc95xx lan78xx
            optional: true
            set-name: eth0
wifis:
    wlan0:
      optional: true
      dhcp4: true
      access-points:
         <Your ESSID>:
           password: <Your Pass-Phrase>
```

Then run..and check and fix any syntax/errors

```
netplan generate
```

Once that command is happy run:-

```
netplan apply
```

You should have networking back..

Comment: Fantastic. Does that lead to the same or a different result than doing $ sudo nmcli d wifi connect "said" password "pwd"?

Comment: Also you need a colon after <your ssid> and I think you need password: before the password.

Comment: Yes sorry vagaries of cut-n-paste.. Have updated..

Comment: I'm not using network manger on my ubuntu boxes.. so I don't even have nmctl running..    The idea with netplan is its the single wrapper around all networking..

Comment: You can add multiple unique <Your ESSID>:  on separate lines if that helps

Comment: I dont even know whether I am running network manager. Starting with ubuntu 20.04 / server edition. Also do you think I need the renderer: clause which some doc said I did?